# How to get a PropertyGrid's cell value (c#)?

Tags: c#, propertygrid

How can I get property grid items and item's value in c# ?
for example :

```
Name : Ali
LastName : Ahmadi
```

(Name and LastName are 2 properties of propertygrid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct answer is :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridItem gi = propertyGrid1.SelectedGridItem;
    while (gi.Parent != null)
    {
        gi = gi.Parent;
    }
    foreach (GridItem item in gi.GridItems)
    {
        ParseGridItems(item); //recursive
    }
}

private void ParseGridItems(GridItem gi)
{
    if (gi.GridItemType == GridItemType.Category)
    {
        foreach (GridItem item in gi.GridItems)
        {
            ParseGridItems(item);
        }
    }
    textBox1.Text += "Lable : "+gi.Label + "\r\n";
    if(gi.Value != null)
        textBox1.Text += "Value : " + gi.Value.ToString() + "\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`PropertyGrid` is just a view over the component-model representation of an object. Rather than look at the grid, I would say: look at the component-model, for example:

```
var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj);
foreach(var prop in props) {
    string name = prop.DisplayName;
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) name = prop.Name;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", name, prop.GetValue(obj));
}
```